# How to access a method of another class(.cs)inside another ascx page(design page)

Tags: c#-4.0

I have 1 method which returns the count of records,i want to access this method in design page(ascx) .how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If your method is in the code-behind class for the ascx then method needs to have public or protected (because ascx class will inherit from code behind class) - then you can use server directives or data binding to access the method - for example

```
<span><%= this.CallMyMethod() %></span>
```

or

```
<span><%# this.CallMyMethod() #></span>
```

For later (data-binding) syntax to work, you must call DataBind method on the parent(ancestor) control.

In case, your method is in another class and its instance method then you need to have instance of that class to call the method. Calling mechanism remains same as above except replace `this` keyword with the variable (instance) of another class. For static methods, you can invoke them using `className.MethodName` syntax. Note that the method has to be accessible from ascx (i.e. public or internal etc).

Comment: The method is inside a class file(.cs) and i need to access in ascx page(design)

Comment: @Shafi - as said what is the relation between class file and acx - is it a code behind class?

Comment: <%= className.MethodName() %> should this be inside a span,because i want to assign it to some variable.how to do that

Comment: @shafi, it don't have to be in span tags - I was just illustrating the usage!

Comment: because it was giving an error like expression expected with or without span.When i saw in event viewer it has error as server tag not formatted properly